# cannot connect to wifi ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have followed [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/142225/connect-to-wep-wireless-network-by-command-line-on-ubuntu)

to try and connect but when I enter my password:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 key pizza1121
```

I receive the error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A)
    Invalid argument "pizza1121".
```

Can someone please help me?! This has messed me up for a while...

Comment: I have just changed my server to ubunutu so I have a GUI, still works great! Thanks for all your efforts though!

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> You can also enter  the  key  as  an  ASCII  string  by  using the s: prefix.

Comment: thank you, I see why it was echoing an error, ill try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously set up wifi on Ubuntu and just need to change the ssid and psk you can just do

sudo nano -w /etc/network/interfaces

Then where it says ssid you put in the networks ssid (network name) and under psk you put your psk (password)